# Load subdomain, hide it from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The setup of my site is as follows:

```
public_html >
/prod/ (http://prod.domain.com)
/test/ (http://test.domain.com)
/dev/ (http://dev.domain.com)
```

For production, testing and development environment.

Using htaccess, all traffic to http://domain.com is rewritten to http://prod.domain.com, but NOT redirected (so that http://domain.com is still visible in the address bar).

The problem is, that relative content on the site, for example a link to "../../contact", now opens http://prod.domain.com/contact, instead of http://domain.com/contact.

Is there a way, to really hide this "prod" subdomain from the url? For example, redirect the user to http://domain.com if http://prod.domain.com is requested, and still rewriting this to http://prod.domain.com?

My htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Set environment
SetEnvIfNoCase HOST ^test\. WP_ENV=testing
SetEnvIfNoCase HOST ^dev\. WP_ENV=development
SetEnvIfNoCase HOST ^acc\. WP_ENV=production
SetEnvIfNoCase HOST (^prod\.|^www\.|^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$) WP_ENV=production NO_AUTH=1

## Require HTTP auth for test
AuthType Basic
AuthName "TESTING"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/htpasswd/hello"
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Allow from localhost
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Require valid-user
Allow from env=NO_AUTH

## Excludes
RewriteRule ^(test)($|/) - [L]

## Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]

## Redirect Old Domain to New Domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.org$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

## Deliver production
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://prod.domain.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Unfortunately we are on a shared hosting, so no access to cmd!

Comment: Couldn't you just add domain.com to the list of virtual hosts on prod.domain.com, and be sure all URLs are root relative?

Comment: How are you generating the URLs? If your browser is pointed at http://domain.com/ and given a relative link, then it will stay on http://domain.com/.

Comment: Could you add the `.htaccess` and/or `httpd.conf` you are currently using to accomplish this?

Comment: For me, iframe would be the solution ;)

Comment: Added htaccess, we're on shared hosting, unfortunately no VPS with cmd access!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an symlink:

`ln -s /public_html/prod /public_html`.

If you would like to access dev files from main domain you can simple change symlink.

Other examples:

`ln -s "prod" <- "main"`

`mklink "main" -> "prod"`

Comment: Unfortunately no cmd access!